# Php Merge Same name Values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get this as output

```
Department  Employee Name   Employee Code   
Sales   Ganeshmurthy    264 
Sales   AZIM ahmed KHAN 2012    
Sales   DHANABAL    231 04-03-2019  
Service RAVIKIRAN   2003    04-03
Manufacturing   RAJAVARMAN  2073    04-03-2019  09:20   1h 10m
Manufacturing   MEGALA  332 04-03-2019  08:14   0h 4m
Manufacturing   SABARI  333 04-03-2019  08:13   0h 3m
Manufacturing   Sasi    1001    04-03-2019  08:16   0h 6m
Manufacturing   FRANCIES XAVIER 136 04-03-2019  08:13   0h 3m
Manufacturing   MANIKANDAN.V    151 04-03-2019  08:15   0h 5m
```

I get this in td format, i need to merge the duplicates into one?
I have an array of several departments and I need to merge same department names into one array. For example If there are `department1`, `department1`, `department1` repeating n numbers of times. I need to merge it to One array as `department1`. How can I achieve this?i need to show it in table - td So the departments should not be getting repeated

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 15
            [department_name] => R&D
            [name] => SUBRAMANIAN
            [code] => 101
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => RAVI
            [code] => 103
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => AMULRAJAN.A
            [code] => 104
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => KANAKARAJ.R
            [code] => 105
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 3
            [department_name] => Manufacturing
            [name] => ELAYARAJA
            [code] => 106
            [clockin] => 
            [late] => 
            [date] => 1970-01-01
        )
```

Expected Result like as below

```
[1] => Array
    (

        [department_name] => Manufacturing

    )

[2] => Array
    (

        [department_name] => R & D

    )
```

Here is what I had tried:

```
foreach($attendance as $dr){
           $alldep = $dr->department_name;
       echo $alldep;
}
```

**Please note i get all datas in array format not as object**

Comment: You should use `array_unique()`

Comment: can you show an example

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this way

```
$uniqArr= array();
foreach ($attendance as $dr) {
    $uniqArr[] = $dr->department_name;;
}
$uniqueRes = array_unique($uniqArr);
```

Comment: i get this output:Array ( [0] => Sales [3] => Service [4] => Manufacturing [17] => COMMERCIAL [19] => DESIGN [20] => GCT/HEAT EXCHANGE/REF DRYER [21] => HRD [22] => MARKETING [23] => MATERIAL )

Comment: how can i echo it

Comment: You have iterate one loop to `echo` each values

Comment: i get array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

Take a new array `$departments`

Loop over the given array.

Append the `department` to `$departments`.

Use `department` as key.

As PHP arrays always have unique keys, you will get only unique departments.

**Working Code:**

```
<?php
$arr = [
[
'department_id' => 15 ,'department_name' => 'R&D' ,'name' => 'SUBRAMANIAN' ,'code' => 101
 ,'clockin' => '' ,'late' => '' ,'date' => '1970-01-01'
],
[
 'department_id' => 3 ,'department_name' => 'Manufacturing' ,'name' => 'RAVI' ,'code' => 103
 ,'clockin' => '' ,'late' => '' ,'date' => '1970-01-01'
],
[
 'department_id' => 3 ,'department_name' => 'Manufacturing' ,'name' => 'AMULRAJAN.A' ,'code' => 104 
 ,'clockin' => '' ,'late' =>'' ,'date' => '1970-01-01'
],
[
 'department_id' => 3 ,'department_name' => 'Manufacturing' ,'name' => 'KANAKARAJ.R' ,'code' => 105
 ,'clockin' => '' ,'late' => '' ,'date' => '1970-01-01'
],
[
 'department_id' => 3 ,'department_name' => 'Manufacturing' ,'name' => 'ELAYARAJA' ,'code' => 106
 ,'clockin' => '' ,'late' => ''
]];

$departments = '';
if (! empty($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $elem) {
 $departments[$elem['department_name']] = $elem['department_name'];
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($departments);echo '</pre>';
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [R&D] => R&D
    [Manufacturing] => Manufacturing
)
```

Comment: i get this error @pupil  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: when i print it in <td> all emoployees having this certain department is repeated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the required output

```
$arr = array_unique(array_column($attendance, 'department_name'));
foreach($arr AS $a)
{
    $newarr[]['department_name'] = $a;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: i get unique values now but when i print that all employeeas having the same depatment is repeated

Comment: Please post the exact output you need with the above data.

Comment: i need to sshow data in table format on <td> but now the same department names are repeated for the all employee having manufacturing

Comment: actually it didnt help

Comment: Why don't you post your exact requirement with some static data?
An array or image could help

Comment: Designation: Manager  : -.john, another row ray ,pokemon all as manager ,then new td sales manager as batista ,triple h etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$department_names = array();

 foreach($attendance as $dr){
   $alldep = $dr->department_name;
   array_push($department_names , array('department_name' => $dr->department_name)); 
}

print_r($department_names$department_names);
```

**Output**

```
[1] => Array
(
    [department_name] => Manufacturing
)
[2] => Array
(
    [department_name] => R & D
)
```